# Silverlight WCF RIA Services. Check result of a boolean method

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

A Silverlight application uses WCF RIA Services for connection to a SQL Server database. Before inserting a bunch of new records into a table, I should check if this table contains any records with a certain value in one of the fields.

My server side method in Domain service class:

```
    [Invoke]
    public bool CheckRec(string nameFilter)
    {
        bool res = false;
        if (this.ObjectContext.MyTest.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == nameFilter) != null)
        {
            res = true;
        }            
        return res;
    }
```

How I could check the method result on the client? 
I'm trying the way like the following, but need some help to implement this correctly:

```
MyTestContext testcontext = new MyTestContext();
string tname =  savetdlg.TNameTBox.Text;
testcontext.CheckRec(tname).Completed += (df, fg) => 
                {
                    bool notunique = ?????? // how to get result of the method?
                    if (notunique == true)
                    {
                        //todo if record exists
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //todo if record doesn't exist
                    }                   
                };
```

Comment: orthogonal, but your check could be written as return this.ObjectContext.MyTest.Any(p => p.Name == nameFilter);

Comment: Depending on the context and the reason for the check, you could also just add that 'if' check to the beginning of the server call that does the inserts.  Of course, if you need it to be 2 separate calls (for instance, the number of records to be uploaded/written is huge and it's pretty common that you won't need to write them), then nevermind. :)

Comment: IMHO you shouldn't use this kind of hooking up to the completed event (or similar kind of event) after the operation has started - if you're going to define the logic in an 'inline' lambda anyway, just call the overload that lets you pass in the Action<InvokeOperation<bool>> instead, IMHO :)  Hooking up to 'completed' after an operation has already started just seems like you're intentionally adding a race condition when it's pretty simple to avoid, although I'll admit it's an unlikely one to hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, done in the following way:

```
MyTestContext testcontext = new MyTestContext();
string tname =  savetdlg.TNameTBox.Text;

testcontext.CheckRec(tname, context_CheckRecCompleted, null);

void context_CheckRecCompleted(InvokeOperation<bool> op)
    {
        bool notunique = op.Value;
        if (notunique == true)
        {
            //todo if record exists
        }
        else
        {
            //todo if record doesn't exist
        }
    }
```

Comment: just curious, why pass the second param as x => context_CheckRecCompleted(x) instead of just context_CheckRecCompleted?  Not that it really matters, just curious :)

Comment: @James Manning Yes, you are right. Corrected the code. Thanks!